# What is the dimension of this set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Consider the set of all linear transformations $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ over $\mathbb{R}$. What
is the dimension of this set, considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with pointwise operation?

**My attempt** : consider the linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$   define by $T(x,y,z)=(x+y,2y,2y-x,0)$

then $T(1,0,0,0)=(1,0,-1,0) , T(0,1,0)=(1,2,2,0)$ and $T(0,0,1)= (0,0,0,0)$

This implies  that dimension of this set  will be  $3$

Am i right/wrong ?

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{im} T$ has dimension $3$. But the problem is about finding the dimension of $\{\textrm{linear transformations } \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^4\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong.

A linear map $T\colon\Bbb R^3\longrightarrow\Bbb R^4$ maps $(x,y,z)$ into$$(ax+by+cz,dx+ey+fz,gx+hy+iz,jx+ky+lz),$$for some real numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l$. But then $T$ can be written in one and only one way as a linear combination of the maps$$T_{11}(x,y,z)=(x,0,0,0),T_{12}(x,y,z)=(y,0,0,0),T_{13}(x,y,z)=(z,0,0,0),$$

$$T_{21}(x,y,z)=(0,x,0,0),T_{22}(x,y,z)=(0,y,0,0),T_{23}(x,y,z)=(0,z,0,0),$$

$$T_{31}(x,y,z)=(0,0,x,0),T_{32}(x,y,z)=(0,0,y,0),T_{33}(x,y,z)=(0,0,z,0),$$
and$$T_{41}(x,y,z)=(0,0,0,x),T_{42}(x,y,z)=(0,0,0,y),T_{43}(x,y,z)=(0,0,0,z).$$So, the dimension of your space is $12(=3\times4)$.

Comment: @jasmine Note that for your linear transformation $T$ (defined as $T(x,y,z)=(x+y,2y,2y-x,0)$) you have $T = T_{11} + T_{12} + 2T_{22} + 2T_{32} - T_{31}$.